# Django - How to avoid multiple processes running same view for same request?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've a Django Application deployed using AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

Sometimes I noticed that a Django view is performed by two different processes.
These situations cause problems: for example, during a file upload, the same file stored two times.

I think that this problem is due to the autoreload option. Is it correct?
How can I fix this?

Update:
The following is my config file:

```
container_commands:
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_createsu:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py createsu"
    leader_only: true
  03_update_permissions:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && python manage.py update_permissions"
    leader_only: true
  04_collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"

option_settings:
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment:
    DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE: "olemshoe.settings_production"
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:
    WSGIPath: olemshoe/wsgi.py
    NumProcesses: 3
    NumThreads: 20
  aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles:
    "/static/": "static/"
```

Should I set `NumProcesses` to 1?

Comment: The [`--noreload`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/django-admin/#cmdoption-runserver-noreload) option is for the Django development server, which you shouldn't be using when you deploy to AWS.

Comment: Thanks @Alasdair, what's your suggestion in order to avoid two process running the same view for the same request?

Comment: I don't have an answer for that, but it's a very different question from the one above.

Comment: Seems to me you are asking the wrong question. Your code should be tolerant of multiple file uploads occurring at the same time. Show the code for how you are handling uploads.